# ModalPopUp NumericUpDownExtender Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, numericupdown, modalpopup

My Code is:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="modalPopup" runat="server">
        <div id="modal" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" Minimum="1"
                runat="server">    
            </cc1:NumericUpDownExtender>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupDragHandleControlID="modal"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1"
        runat="server">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here, modal popup was not showing my numeric updown extender, i dont know what was the issue here.FYI: Im running my code in IE8.

Comment: My code is visible now, give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a value in the Width Property of the NumericUpDownExtender Control.

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLeftNumeric" Width="50px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="ajaxNumericLeft" 
                                   runat="server" Width="60"
                                   TargetControlID="txtLeftNumeric">
</ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>
```